# How to convert ply to vtk in python?

Tags: vtk, converters, ply-file-format

I have around 500 .ply files that need to be converted to vtk file. I usually use Paraview to convert them manually, but it takes forever. I wonder if there is a tool to convert ply files into vtk files in Python?

Thanks in advance.